# Divi theme causing white screen error on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am getting a white screen of death error on my wordpress site.
I tried to figure it out by deactivating all the plugins and making the them active one by one and figure out that the plugin is working properly. I did the same white themes.

**And found:** 
The Divi theme creates the white screen error.

I  have divi theme as a parent theme, if i deactivate the divi theme and active some other theme then the website works proper.

Don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Since you have the Divi theme, I guess you'd have access to Elegant Theme's support. Are you able to and have you tried opening a ticket with them? Another option is you may be able to access Divi rollback to downgrade to a previous theme version to see if you can pinpoint the version causing the issue: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/theme-releases/introducing-divi-rollback-easily-roll-back-to-a-previously-installed-version-of-divi-with-a-single-click

Comment: Hello Richard k, thank you for your answer. I rolled back the Divi theme version and it resolved the issue.